# Importing tidyverse and dplyr but piping function %>% still not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying the following code to get prices from Yahoo however I am getting a error that the pipe function is not found.:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
#To get the data from the internet first create ticker symbols
symbols = c("SPY", "EFA", "IJS", "EEM", "AGG")
# Get daily prices for ETFs. 
library(purrr)
library(quantmod)
prices = getSymbols(symbols, src= "yahoo", from ="2012-12-31", to = "2023-04-30", auto.assign =        TRUE, warnings = FALSE)
prices %>% 
map(~Ad(get(.))) %>%       
reduce(merge) %>% 
colnames= (symbols)
```

I have tried the first two packages and I have noticed that magrittr is never imported. I thought this was the issue and have tried importing magrittr package with the two packages and even by itself. I just downloaded R and Rstudio a couple of days ago and saw that there was a recent update so maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Just use the native pipe `|>`

Comment: Using the native pipe does not solve the problem which is likely related to synthatic errors in the last line of code

Comment: @Phil, the OP did not ask about the native pipe, but clearly the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`.

Comment: @mhovd And my answer is that the solution to his problem can be found just by using the native pipe. Even the Posit people agree that `|>` is preferred over `%>%` and no longer develop the magrittr package. So why not just make the switch and call it a day.

Comment: Thank you seems like the native pipe is preferred with the new R update. I could not get the magrittr pipe to work but native pipe worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be with the last line of your script. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps it's:

```
prices %>% 
  map(~Ad(get(.))) %>%       
  reduce(merge) %>% 
  set_colnames(symbols)
```

Or just drop the last line, as it doesn't really seem to do much that is useful. All is fine with the pipe, really.

Either way, you definitely don't want the equal sign between a function and the bracket as you are currently doing in the last line there.